Does Python's shutil.make_archive write temporary files when compressing a directory?
We are using shutil.make_archive to zip a directory. This is being done in a pod (docker container) in Kubernetes. Sometimes the pod crashes when the directory is being zipped. The pod is showing an increase in usage of ephemeral storage before crashing. The directory being zipped is in a declared volume with plenty of disc space. The the shutil command is:
shutil.make_archive('/data/4548-2024052012-gfsforecast/final/cogeo/maxele63', 'zip', root_dir='/data/4548-2024052012-gfsforecast/final/cogeo', base_dir='maxele63')

where /data is the declared volume.
Does shutil.make_archive write temporary files to /var/tmp of any other system directory? We have checked /var/tmp and the home directory (/home/user) during compression and have not found any files or increase in directory (du -k /var/tmp) size.
We are trying to find if shutil.make_archive may be writing temporary files to some other system directory or if it even writes temporary files.

Maybe you could [edit] and explain more about the problem you're trying to solve. If the answer was "yes, in /some/path", what would you do with that knowledge? Are you trying to find the cause of the crash? Do you try to recover a crashed archiving session? Just trying to rule out the XY problem.

"Does shutil.make_archive write temporary files to /var/tmp of any other system directory?" Run it locally under control of strace and see where it is creating files.

Try setting TMPDIR to a location on the volume in question and see if that resolves the problem. Many things that create temporary files respect the TMPDIR environment variable.

We will try setting TMPDIR. Thanks!
